# Signing JAR but file still does not work as a Java Web Start Application

Tags: java, jar, jar-signing

I've followed everything I could find online about making Java Web start applications. I did sign my jar, however when I verify it I get the following:

[image]

And when I try to use the jar in a web start application, I get the security warning about unsigned applications. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Oh, also, the jar was made using eclipse, if that helps at all.

This is what the warning looks like, the application runs but nothing works:

[image]

The JNLP is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase=
"mydomain" 
    href="/webstart.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Game of Life</title>
        <vendor>My name</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.7+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="/GoL.jar"
            main="true" />

    </resources>
    <application-desc
         name="The Game of Life"
         main-class=
           "Frame"
         width="857"
         height="636">
     </application-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Do you have a trusted certificate by [CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) like (verisign.. etc)..?

Comment: No... am I required to have one for my webstart applications to work at all? I was under the impression I wasn't

Comment: You can but you'll get UNKNOWN PUBLISHER, could you add the image about UNSIGNED APPLICATION and post your jnlp

Comment: I added all of that, thanks for your help man. I hope this question isn't too stupid.

Comment: Did you trying opening `Gol.jar`  and see its `manifest.mf` and see if it's signed?, the jar that is in "myDomain"

Comment: Sorry for the late response, the GoL.jar does have a signed manifest.mf, I checked in the command prompt window shown above.